# Making an Ascii table from a FITS file header

Tags: python, ascii, astronomy, fits

I'd like to learn how to grab information from a FITS file header and transfer that information to an ascii table. For example, this is how I would obtain the info.:

```
import pyfits
a = pyfits.open('data.fits')
header = a[0].header # Which should return something like this (It is  BinHDUlist)
SIMPLE  =                T / conforms to FITS standards                    
                               / institution responsible for creating this file 
TELESCOP= 'Kepler  '           / telescope                                      
INSTRUME= 'Kepler Photometer'  / detector type                                  
OBJECT  = 'KIC 8631743'        / string version of KEPLERID                     
RA_OBJ  =           294.466516 / [deg] right ascension                          
DEC_OBJ =            44.751131 / [deg] declination
```

How could I create an ASCII table that contains RA_OBJ and DEC_OBJ ?

EDIT: I'd like to create a .dat file that contains two columns (RA and DEC) from the headers. Here is an example of what I am trying:

```
import asciitable
import asciidata
import pyfits
import numpy as np

# Here I have taken all the fits files in my current directory and did the following:
# ls > z.txt so that all the fits files are in one place.

a = asciidata.open('z.txt')
i = 0 #There are 371 fits files in z.txt
while i<=370:
    b = pyfits.open(a[0][i])
    h = b[0].header
    RA = np.array([h['RA_OBJ']])
    DEC = np.array(h['DEC_OBJ']])
    asciitable.write({'RA': RA, 'DEC': DEC}, 'coordinates.dat', names=['RA', 'DEC'])
    i = i+1
```

I'd like for this to write a .dat file containing something like this:

```
RA    DEC
###   ###
...   ...
...   ...
...   ...
```

Instead, my code just writes over the keys of the previous files. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you might benefit from reading [the pyfits documentation](http://stsdas.stsci.edu/download/docs/The_PyFITS_Handbook.pdf) more carefully. The header attribute is a `pyfits.header.Header` object, which is a dictionary-like object. So you can do something like:

```
import pyfits

keys = ['SIMPLE', 'TELESCOP', 'INSTRUME', 'OBJECTS', 'RA_OBJ', 'DEV_OBJ']

hdulist = pyfits.open("data.fits")
header = hdulist[0].header
for k in keys:
    print k, "=", header[k]
```

You can add more fancy outputting, put the resulting string in variable, checking for missing keys, etc.

**EDIT**:

Here's how this could be coupled with `asciitable` and `numpy`:

```
import asciitable
import numpy as np

keys = ['RA', 'DEC']
data = {}

# Initialize "data" with empty lists for each key
for k in keys:
    data[k] = []

# Collect all data in the "data" dictionary
for i in range(0, 50):
    data['RA'].append(np.array(i))
    data['DEC'].append(np.array(i+1))

asciitable.write(data, "coords.dat", names=keys)
```

Comment: Thank you for your input @Fabian Fagerholm, I made an edit to my question that I am hoping that you could address. Your suggestion does work, but I'd like to record the output into a .dat file along with keys from the headers of many other .fits files via while-loop.

Comment: Don't keep changing the question, I might not be able to keep up! ;) It seems that asciitable is designed to write all data in one go. That makes sense because some data might change the needed column widths, for example. So what happens is that you overwrite the file in every iteration of your loop. Anyway, here's how you can do it: you need to make a dictionary with your columns as keys, and each value should be a list of data for the rows. So in your loop, you would append values to data['RA'] and data['DEC'], and then write the whole thing using asciitable.write(data, ...) after the loop.

Comment: I don't really understand how to make columns out of the keys. I get what you're saying, I just do not know how to do it.

Comment: @DaxFeliz: No worries. I added an example to show how to do it. You need to adapt it to your case, of course. This is a good chance to get some practise with basic Python data structures. Good luck! :)